# How do I get Folium to display maps in English?

Tags: python, localization, folium

I am starting to learn [folium](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/docs-v0.6.0/quickstart.html#Styling-function).  The simplest thing, in Jupyter notebook, is to do:

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[33.24, 36.98])
m
```

This displays a map all of whose place names are in Arabic.  Is there a switch to get it to display the same places in English?

Comment: try for language support. You should check folium docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Folium itself doesn't have any language parameters, so you'd have to pick a map source that's all English.

If you sign up for [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/signup/), you can get access to plenty of tile sets for free including the all English `mapbox.run-bike-hike` tile set.

Once you sign up for Mapbox, they'll give you an API token to use. Then, you can pass your API Key and tile set to Folium.

```
import folium
m = folium.Map(location=[33.24, 36.98],
               tiles="https://api.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.run-bike-hike/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.XXX")
m
```

Replace pk.XXX with your own access token

Comment: This is helpful but comes with a price tag, do you know of free English tile sets?

Comment: I got **ValueError at /
Custom tiles must have an attribution.**

Comment: Added `attr=atr,`  `atr = "<a href=https://www.mapbox.com//>Map Box</a>"`. The map was Grey.

Answer (score 1):

Other free tiles will work too:

```
folium.Map(
    location=[30.5928, 114.3055],
    tiles='Stamen Toner',
    zoom_start= 6
)
```

Comment: How can I get English for the default map? OpenStreetMap tile.